# TYPO3 extbase - add MM relation with additional field

Tags: field, typo3, relation, extbase

I have a basic news extension with a m:m relation to the fe_users table.
This relation is used for knowing which user accessed which news, so when the user accesses the details view of some news, an entry is added in the MM table.

What I want also, is to have a int field (a unix timestamp) which tells when the user accessed the news.

I know I could just add a TIEMSTAMP field with CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as default, but I may have to add other information beside it, so how could I do this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about creating a e.g. Visitation Object wich stores the user, a timestamp and all the information you'd like and make a mm relation to this table instead ob fe_users?

Comment: Yep, it looks like this approach has more sense if more attributes related to visitation will have to be added. For now I'll stick with the timestamp field. Thank you!